# Meteor without a router?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Meteor is obviously dedicated to being ultra-simple.  But it doesn't include any page routing in its out of the box configuration.  So if you can't use iron-router (because of a conflict with some other package), does that mean you have to use Blaze.render() and the templates directly to change your pages?

I've looked at the docs about this and it just doesn't seem ultra-simple, to say the least.  So I'm hoping that I'm missing something.  Like there's a reasonably simple way to control what template is being displayed without getting into all the view objects that have to be destroyed when you're done with them and what-not.

It seems strange that a product devoted to ultra-simplicity would have such basic functionality  embedded in objects and functions that are non-trivial compared to most of the rest of the API. But if they really expect beginners to use iron-router, why isn't it part of Meteor to begin with?

Comment: out of curiosity, what package is iron:router conflicting with?

Comment: Try to recreate the leaderboard example without using any framework, and you'll see how simple it is to do it with Meteor.

Comment: @stubailo -- AmMaps (a mapping library by AmCharts).  I can add iron-router and AmMaps still works, but as soon as I add even a single call to the Router object, it stops (without any error messages).

Comment: @PeppeL-G -- thanks for the suggestion.  I will do just that!

Comment: Interesting - if you had a repro on GitHub I could take a look at why it doesn't work, seems interesting.

Comment: I am going to put the project on Github.  I'll put the mapping package up there too, b/c I had do the packaging myself on it.  I'll send you a message.  I would like to know what's going on, too.  Thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1):

Check out `Template.dynamic`: https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic

This will let you include a template by name, and pass the name in from a helper.

The other option is to use a Session variable instead of routing, and have `{{#if}}` statements:

```
{{#if firstPage}}
  {{> firstPageTemplate}}
{{else}}
  {{> otherPageTemplate}}
{{/if}}
```

Comment: The docs on that Template.dynamic feature seem sparse and confusing.  It says you can define the templateName with a helper, but does that mean you do a: Template.dynamic.helpers() or you have to register a global helper?  I hope the second method you wrote up works, b/c it is very intuitive.  I have seen it before, but I thought that Blaze had broken that approach.  Thanks so much, stubailo!

Comment: The second approach is actually used in a lot of Meteor internal apps that were written before any kind of routing was available, so it definitely still works! As for the helper thing, you would define the helper either globally or on the template inside which you are calling Template.dynamic (Template.dynamic doesn't refer to an actual template, it's just like #if or #else in that it's built into the language)